# How to address widget created by user?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using a simple function, which creates rectangles on the canvas (with sizes stated by the user).

```
def create_some_rectangle(self):
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(master, x0, y0, x1, y1, fill='somecolor')
    # user specify x0 y0 x1 y1
```

But I want to add something for future addressing (highlighting particular widget by a click of the mouse). It would be simple if there will be 1 rectangle, but the user creates a lot of them so I need something special to highlight every widget individually.

1. User click left mouse button on the widget
2. Widget highlights
3. User click on canvas (except highlighted widget) and highlight expires

How could I realize that? Are some methods existing for this \ any helpful idea?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create an object on the canvas, the function will return a unique integer identifier. You can use this id to reference the object.

You can also give the object a unique tag, which can be any string you want except a string of only digits (since it would clash with the id).

In your scenario, when the user clicks on an object you can save the identifier of the object they clicked on. You can then use that identifier later to "expire" the highlighting.

Comment: I approximately understand this, but how to 1. get this id 2. address to the widget using this id?

Comment: @codY (1) `id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(...)`. (2) `self.canvas.itemconfig(id, fill="red")`

Answer (score 1):

Every method `create_XXX` gives `id` of created object

```
id = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
```

which you can keep on list to have access to all objects when it will be needed.

To change object's option you can use this `id`

```
canvas.itemconfig(id, fill='blue')
```

You can bind to `Canvas` function which will be executed when you click left button (`<Button-1>`)

```
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)
```

And this function will get `event` with mouse position `event.x`, `event.y` which you can use to find object on canvas

```
selected_id = canvas.find_overlapping(event.x, event.y, event.x+1, event.y+1)
```

And now you can deselect all items and select only clicked item

```
for id_ in all_ids:
    canvas.itemconfig(id_, fill='red')

if selected_id:
    canvas.itemconfig(selected_id, fill='blue')
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def on_click(event):
    #print(event)

    selected_id = canvas.find_overlapping(event.x, event.y, event.x+1, event.y+1)
    print(selected_id)

    for id_ in all_ids:
        canvas.itemconfig(id_, fill='red')

    if selected_id:
        canvas.itemconfig(selected_id, fill='blue')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.pack()

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)

all_ids = []

for x in range(10, 301, 60):
    id_ = canvas.create_rectangle((x, 10, x+50, 60), fill='red')
    all_ids.append(id_)

root.mainloop()
```

Doc: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method)